# Add replies to Android notifications while using react-native-firebase

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

Android 7.0 introduced the ability for users to [enter text directly into a notification in order to respond to it](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#reply-action), without opening the app. I am using the [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) project in order to receive push notifications in my React Native app.

Based on the documentation it seems like this functionality is supported 
 -- specifically, [AndroidNotification.addAction](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.3.x/notifications/reference/AndroidNotification#addAction) and [AndroidAction.addRemoteInput](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.3.x/notifications/reference/AndroidAction#addRemoteInput) would seem to indicate that this is possible.

However, I can't find any examples on how to correctly implement this feature. Is this feature supported in a React Native project using `react-native-firebase`?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is possible:

1. Update your `AndroidManifest.xml` file to include the following:

   ```
   <receiver android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseBackgroundNotificationActionReceiver" android:exported="true">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.BackgroundAction"/>
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseBackgroundNotificationActionsService"/>
   ```
2. Add a .js file (e.g., `backgroundMessaging.js`) containing the following:

   ```
   import firebase from 'react-native-firebase'
   export const backgroundMessageListener = async (message) => {
       const notification = new firebase.notifications.Notification()

       // TODO: Configure your notification here...

       // https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.3.x/notifications/reference/AndroidAction
       const action = new firebase.notifications.Android.Action('reply', 'ic_launcher', 'Reply')

       action.setShowUserInterface(false)

       // https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.0.x/notifications/reference/AndroidRemoteInput
       const remoteInput = new firebase.notifications.Android.RemoteInput("input")
       remoteInput.setLabel('Reply')
       action.addRemoteInput(remoteInput)

       notification.android.addAction(action)

       firebase.notifications().displayNotification(notification)

       return Promise.resolve()
   }

   export const backgroundActionHandler = async (notificationOpen) => {
       if (notificationOpen.action === 'reply') {
           // TODO: Handle the input entered by the user here...
           console.log(notificationOpen);
       }

       return Promise.resolve();
   };
   ```
3. Update `index.js` as follows:

   ```
   import { backgroundMessageListener, backgroundActionHandler } from './backgroundMessaging'

   AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage', () => backgroundMessageListener)
   AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('RNFirebaseBackgroundNotificationAction', () => backgroundActionHandler);
   ```

Notes:
This example assumes that you've already configured `react-native-firebase` and followed the setup guide [here](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.3.x/notifications/android). The `backgroundMessageListener` function will get called when your app is not in the foreground and a "data" notification is received. The [Receiving Notifications](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.3.x/notifications/receiving-notifications) has examples on how to perform additional setup such as requesting permission to receive notifications.

Comment: Not showing actions in android when app is in background or app is closed .Can you please tell me exactly how can i achieve same from react-native firebase .
Thanks in advance

Comment: I've done this and it works perfectly, except when I submit the input in the notification it loads forever, even though I call `Promise.resolve()`

Comment: @PalKerecsenyi see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

To add to what @Donut has answered, things have changed a bit now.

AndroidManifest.xml (remains unchanged as per @Donut)

```
<receiver android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseBackgroundNotificationActionReceiver" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.BackgroundAction"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseBackgroundNotificationActionsService"/>
```

It is recommended that you add a channel-id here (i.e. app-local-notifications)

```
<meta-data
 android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>
```

Your backgroundMessaging.js should now be

```
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase'

const channelId = 'app-local-notifications'

export const backgroundMessageListener = async (message) => {
    const channel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel(
        channelId,
        'Local Interactive Notifications',
        firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max
    ).setDescription('Local Interactive Notifications');
    firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);

    const localNotification = new firebase.notifications.Notification({
        sound: 'default' //important
    })
        .setNotificationId(message.messageId)
        .setTitle(message.data.title)
        .setBody(message.data.body)
        .android.setChannelId(channelId) //important
        .android.setSmallIcon('ic_launcher')
        .android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.High); //important

    const action = new firebase.notifications.Android.Action('reply', 'ic_launcher', 'Reply')
    action.setShowUserInterface(false)

    const remoteInput = new firebase.notifications.Android.RemoteInput("inputText")
    remoteInput.setLabel('Message')
    action.addRemoteInput(remoteInput)

    localNotification.android.addAction(action)
    firebase.notifications().displayNotification(localNotification).catch(err => console.log(err)); //important
}

export const backgroundActionHandler = async (notificationOpen) => {
    if (notificationOpen && notificationOpen.notification) {
        const action = notificationOpen.action;
        const notificationId = notificationOpen.notification.notificationId;
        if (action === "reply") {
            console.log(notificationOpen)
        } else {
            console.log("unsupported action", action);
        }
        // hide the notification instead of Promise.resolve()
        firebase.notifications().removeDeliveredNotification(notificationId); //important
    }
};
```

Things to note:
1. Notification sent via FCM should be `data-only` notifications.
2. Notification priority should be "high".
3. Notification action must not take longer than 60s.
4. ChannelID is required.
5. Notification sound should be default.